# How to search for tables alike? npgsql.NET & PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, npgsql

I cannot find out how to search up tables with a similar name. on MySQL, it's `SHOW TABLES LIKE`, but I've heard on PostgreSQL it's `/dt "table-name"*`, and I also tried `/dt *"table-name"*` and `/dt *table-name*`, but none seemed to work.

Error:

```cs
Npgsql.PostgresException: '42601: syntax error at or near "\"

POSITION: 1'
```

Code:

```cs
await connection.OpenAsync();

string query = $@"\dt ""{tbSearch.Text}""*";
NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(query, connection);
```

Honestly my current experience with PostgreSQL has been so bad. MySQL is somehow better and faster & it's a lot less vague.

Comment: I have no experience with either, but when you want to search with a forward slash and start your query with a backward slash - that might be a hint?

Comment: @riffnl It says the error is present in `POSITION: 1'`. So it's because of the `\ `. I've also tried using `/` instead of the backward slash, still no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\dt` is a psql shortcut which won't work elswhere.

Instead, you can query `pg_tables`

```
select * 
from pg_tables 
where tablename ilike '%test%';
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I decided to switch back to MySQL. PostgreSQL is a lot slower than MySQL and is a lot more annoying. This could be an answer for people who are facing the same issue.